# database backup and restore yii2 using Beaten-Sect0r / yii2-db-manager

Tags: database, yii2, backup

I want to add database backup and restore in my yii2 basic project .For this i have added extension  Beaten-Sect0r / yii2-db-manager through composer.I have added following code in config/web.php:

```
    'modules' => [
    'db-manager' => [
        'class' => 'bs\dbManager\Module',
        // path to directory for the dumps
        'path' => '@app/backups',
        // list of registerd db-components
        'dbList' => ['db'],
        'as access' => [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

I also created a writable directory named backup on app root directory.
Now how do i access backup functionality?Should i create view,model and controller to do so?I used url to access backup form like this localhost:8081/myproj/web/index.php?r=db-manager and its not working. Following Error appears.[image]

Comment: Usage clearly mentioned in link: https://github.com/Beaten-Sect0r/yii2-db-manager#usage

Comment: i have visited that link previously.what will be the url to open the page to take backup of database ,Im confused.I used http://localhost:8081/myproj/web/index.php?r=default and its not working.

Comment: Try using: localhost:8081/myproj/web/index.php?r=db-manager

Comment: i tried that also but error as incuded above appears

Comment: It clearly says it can't find the directory @app/backups. I think you should check the path of the backups folder.

Comment: ok its worked for me now.Name for backup folder was mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your path (@app/backups) is not writable! Check chmod!